# Cant upload .exe file to FTP server

Tags: ftp

When I try to upload an executable to my ftp server, its getting instantly deleted after it's been uploaded. Same goes with .mp4, .dll and any other files that are no text files or .zip/.rar.
I am quite sure that youre usually able to upload any file to your ftp server, so does anybody have a solution?

Comment: StackOverflow is mainly for programming questions. You might want to try your question over at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the server has some kind of filter to prevent abuse by an unauthorized party, as executables can contain malware.

Speak to the provider and ask them.

Also if you just want to store the `.exe` file maybe compressing it into an archive and uploading the archive might be sufficient?